# Why Order email is going to two different customers in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email

I am placing an order on my website. The order email is going to two different email. Another email is choosing randomly.

Why is this happening? 
What is the issue?

http://nimb.ws/mYL6tS

Answer (score 0):

I think that you send a **copy** of email to the other E-mail, please check this config :

`System->Configuration->Order->Send order Email Copy To` or check if you have installed some module that does this behavior.

Good luck.

Comment: I have checked the configuration in which email is configured. But the issue is that every time email is triggered to different email id. It must be sent to the configured email id.